# imposing a value to a variable using if condition

Tags: java

I have input like 12 inch & I want to do as:

```
if (unites.equals("inch"))
  inches=measurement;
```

Here, measurement is a double & unites is a string.

Comment: Nice of you to tell us that, but since this is site is no diary ... what is your question?

Comment: look at parse double.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
double unitesValue = Double.parseDouble(unites);
```

Comment: So when `unites` is equal to *"inch"* you want parse that to `double`? Yes, makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes when the condition become true, then you parse the units string to double, then do your calculation

Comment: What is the `double` of *"inch"*?